# Unable to ssh into remote Linux by ngrok

Tags: linux, ssh, tcp, ngrok

The remote Linux computer is in an internal network and has no public IP address. So I installed ngrok.

```
ngrok tcp 22
```

> ngrok by @inconshreveable      (Ctrl+C to quit)
>   Tunnel Status        online
>   Version            2.0.19/2.0.17
>   Web Interface      http://127.0.0.1:4040
>   Forwarding         tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:36428 ->
>   localhost:22
>   Connections    ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
>                 0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00

I checked that sshd is running.

At the local PC, I tried

```
ssh myuser@ngrok.com -p36428
```

which gave rise to

> ssh: connect to host ngrok.com port 36428: Connection refused

Comment: Note that `myuser` is the username for the local username on the machine, not the username for ngrok. (For anyone who stumbled on this problem and found this site)

Comment: While the problem is on Linux, if you cannot SSH to Ngrok on Windows see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67193433/unable-to-ssh-to-a-windows-machine-using-ngrok

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You are connecting to the wrong destination address.  The command should be

```
ssh myuser@0.tcp.ngrok.io -p36428
```

Notice the different hostname (ie `0.tcp.ngrok.io` instead of `ngrok.com`).

And generally you would want to put the `user@hostname` after all the options (eg `-p36428`), even though it doesn't generally cause any issues.

Comment: Good point but another frustrated factor is that the ngrok server is blocked by China gov.

Comment: maybe use serveo @Lee