# Unable to access ssh using ngrok

Tags: ssh

I want to expose my system for accessing via ssh.

After running this `./ngrok tcp 12345`, I see:

```
Forwarding                    tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:15909 -> localhost:12345
```

In my `~/.ssh/config`, I add the following lines, as I have a proxy in my workplace:

```
Host ngrok
  Hostname 0.tcp.ngrok.io
  ProxyCommand corkscrew 172.16.2.30 8080 %h %p
```

To test, I am trying to access my own system from my own system (another shell) via ngrok. Then finally when I access using

```
ssh -p 15909 ngrok
```

it says:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

How do I access it?

Comment: If you are on Windows for SSH-ing to ngrok, this would be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67193433/unable-to-ssh-to-a-windows-machine-using-ngrok

Answer (score 2):

See [Unable to ssh into remote Linux by ngrok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577729/unable-to-ssh-into-remote-linux-by-ngrok#30581507)

but also try this from the new shell when you want to ssh into your ngrok

```
ssh <username>@0.tcp.ngrok.io -p 15909
```

where username is the user your sshing into